# Vstack to get array

Tags: python, matrix, haar-wavelet, vstack

Im trying to put the vector i get from z in A and from q in B and then stacking them together. arr is an array from image of size (600,478). M=600, N=478. For some reason the matrix i get out is not the right one.

```
def avgdif(M):
    A=np.zeros([int(M/2),N])
    B=np.zeros([int(M/2),N])
    for i in range(int(M/2)):
        z=(np.add(arr[2*i-1],arr[2*i]))/2
        A[i:]=[z] 
        q=(np.subtract(arr[2*i-1],arr[2*i]))/2
        B[i:]=[q]
        
        
        
        
    return np.vstack([A,B])
```

Comment: I am guessing your np.vstack([A,B]) should not be square brackets

Comment: Where do you define `arr`? Consider making a smaller example that can be executed.

Comment: arr is `image = Image.open('randompicture.jpg').convert('L')

arr =np.array(image)

print(np.shape(arr))

M=len(arr)
N=len(arr[0]) `